# VHDL Cannot Drive Load pins

Tags: vhdl, synthesis

Using the first snippet of code, I have been getting this error that a bunch of my signals drove no pins. I am pretty certain that this is because in the first snippet of code, the first if statement is never reached. Why would this be so? In the second snippet I modified the code, and all of my problems have been fixed. I made the change as an intuitive impulse, I have no idea why that fixed everything. Could someone explain maybe how the Synthesizer generates the circuit?

First Snippet:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity DataReg is
    generic(N: integer := 8);
    port(DIN: in std_logic_vector(N - 1 downto 0);
    DOUT: out std_logic_vector(N - 1 downto 0);
    CLK: in std_logic;
    ENABLE: in std_logic;
    RESET: in std_logic);
end DataReg;

architecture Behavioral of DataReg is
begin
    process(CLK, ENABLE)    
    begin
        if rising_edge(CLK) and ENABLE = '1' then
            DOUT <= DIN;
        end if;

        if rising_edge(CLK) and RESET = '1' then
            DOUT <= (others => '0');
        end if;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Second snippet: (Fixed code)

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity DataReg is
    generic(N: integer := 8);
    port(DIN: in std_logic_vector(N - 1 downto 0);
    DOUT: out std_logic_vector(N - 1 downto 0);
    CLK: in std_logic;
    ENABLE: in std_logic
    RESET: in std_logic);
end DataReg;

architecture Behavioral of DataReg is
begin
    process(CLK, ENABLE)    
    begin
        if rising_edge(CLK) then
            if ENABLE = '1' then
                DOUT <= DIN;
            elsif RESET = '1' then
                DOUT <= (others => '0');
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: could it be that `RESET` is fixed at `'1'` somewhere else in the code? (Or `ENABLE` at `'0'`..)

Comment: Those aren't snippets. VHDL calls them design units, two sets of design units each consisting of a primary design unit (entity) and a secondary design unit (architecture). The structures for inferring sequential logic were originally standardized (IEEE Std 1076.6-2004, now withdrawn, VHDL RTL Synthesis), and a form involving an if statement requires the reset and clock edge evaluation to be a single if statement (and your second 'snippet' does that).  Without identifying the synthesis vendor, their documentation will specify at least some of the supported (preferred) forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because HDL code must be able to represent existing hardware. Therefore when you write RTL (Register Transfer Level) code you have to stick to certain structures. Even the second code you wrote is not correct.

I can't explain all the rules but basically, to use an edge (rising or falling) you can have only one signal. Not OR-es or And-es etc.:
  `if rising_edge(CLK) then`

In such a clocked section your process can have one or two more sensitivity signals. Often there is an asynchronous reset in some exceptional cases there is also an asynchronous set. For those to work you have to place the condition **before** the clock. Therefore your code is wrong. Your ENABLE and RESET are only looked at when there is a clock edge. Thus putting ENABLE in the sensitivity list is superfluous. You might just as well leave it out.

Furthermore the ENABLE `if` is before the RESET. Thus if the ENABLE is high your RESET will be ignored. Probably not what you want!

The code for a clocked section is sooo terribly standard that I often copy a template I have laying around. (I always use asynchronous active low reset)

```
process(clk, reset_n) 
begin
    if (reset_n='0') then

    elsif rising_edge(clk) then

    end if; -- reset/clocked
end process;
```

Comment: I'm not sure that there's anything wrong with the synchronous reset in his code, just the implied priority of enable/reset seems odd. Personally I would not recommend using asynchronous resets as the default choice.

Comment: I did not say that synchronous resets are bad. I come from the ASIC world where asynchronous reset are preferred. Also in an FPGA I would not use them as they use-up resources.

Comment: Fair enough in ASIC world, I don't know much about that. What's the scenario where a sync reset uses more resource in an FPGA?

Comment: You need to feed the reset into the LUT to force the input to zero costing you an input. But most (all?) FPGA's already have an asynchronous reset network to the registers costing you nothing.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the two pieces of code that you present are not even equivalent in the simulator because when `ENABLE` and `RESET` are both `1` on a clock edge, the first snippet results in `DOUT` being `00000000` whereas in the second one it evaluates to `DIN`.

It is my impression that the sensitivity lists (the part in parentheses after `process`) are ignored during synthesis by Xilinx Vivado.  I consider them a relic from times when simulation tools could not afford deducing which variables should be monitored to determine when variables should be updated.  I don't know what other synthesis tools do with them.

Anyway, you specified `ENABLE` in your sensitivity list, which means that you want to evaluate the process statements if `ENABLE` changes value.  All if-statements evaluate to false unless a rising clock edges is taking place.  Therefore, `CLK` alone in the sensitivity list is sufficient for simulation.

All that being said, **you should restrict your code to formats that are explicitly recommended by the synthesis tool vendor**.  Synthesis tools can only implement a subset of everything that you can write in VHDL.  For Vivado, you can find suggested code structure in the [synthesis manual](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2017_3/ug901-vivado-synthesis.pdf) (This one is for Vivado 2017.3).  On page 71, you will see that they recommend flip-flops of the form:

```
process(clk) is
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        if clr = '1' then
            dout <= "00000000";
        elsif ce = '1' then
            dout <= d_in;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

You can rename the variables as needed of course.  On page 69, you will also see that Xilinx recommends using synchronous implementations (putting everything inside the `rising_edge` if-statement) over asynchronous implementations.  There is much more in the manual, for example about how to write shift registers or RAMs, which you should become familiar with if you want to write code to be synthesized with Vivado.  Other vendors have similar documentation with recommended code.

Comment: "you should restrict your code to formats that are explicitly recommended by the synthesis tool vendor" good advise, but not strictly true. The problem is for instance that tool vendors don't regularly update their user guides. Xilinx is for instance still using the deprecated package `std_logic_arith` in their guidelines...

Comment: *I consider them a relic from times when simulation tools could not afford deducing which variables should be monitored.... I don't know what other synthesis tools do with them.* IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 (withdrawn, RTL Synthesis), 5. Verification methodology "The process of verifying synthesis results using simulation consists of applying equivalent inputs to both the original model and synthesized...." Separate analysis (compile) and elaboration (linking/loading) requires sensitivity lists. Limiting sensitivity lists e.g. ( clk, rst) can improve performance over reserved word **all** in -2008.